# C# Chess Game - Resizing the board automatically upon resizing its WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, image-resizing, window-resize

Well the title pretty much says it all...I'm building a C# WinForms chess game and am trying to implement the ability to resize the board.

I currently have a form with `FormBorderStyle` set to `Sizable` and [this `TableLayoutPanel`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64884336/h/panel.txt) on it, as well as [this `Layout` event handler](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64884336/h/layout.txt).

```
private void Form1_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    panBoard.SuspendLayout();

    int xDiff = this.Size.Width - oldSize.Width;
    int yDiff = this.Size.Width - oldSize.Height;
    int diff = xDiff > yDiff ? xDiff : yDiff;

    this.Size = new Size(oldSize.Width +
    diff, oldSize.Height + diff);
    sizeXY += diff;
    game.SizeXY = sizeXY;

    panBoard.ResumeLayout();
}
```

When I run the app and resize the form, the background image gets scaled slightly too much, as shown by [these two pictures](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zl9qbnaifnacxsd/UzRlvy0zg5). The `TableLayoutPanel`'s cell borders should line up nicely with the cells in the image. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? MTIA :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep....Using those pictures is definitely a better solution. But do allow me to also show off a dirty trick that I used few years back for an application I made for myself.

I took a form and added a `TableLayoutPanel` in it. Set `TableLayoutPanel.Dock` property to `Fill`. Set the Form size to be a square (400 * 400 for ex.). Set `TableLayoutPanel` columns and rows as 8 and set width as `Percentage` to 50 to all. Then I would like to generate `Panel` at runtime and add them to each box in `TableLayoutPanel` by using a logical `for` loop. Change the `BackColor` of each alternate panel at runtime (to appear them as chess). Set `Dock` property of each panel to `Fill`. You can play with `Margin` property of panel to look them better. Run your aplication and everything should as expected.

Few advantages of this trick is, you can easily change the color of your chess board anytime. Number of boxes in `TableLayoutPanel` can also be changed (if its not chess). I know this is something which you were not looking for, but definitely something you can consider. It will not make your application heavy as well. And trust me, the output looks cool.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much **exactly** what I'm trying to acheive already! And I already thought of not using a bg image and just alternating the `BackColor` property of cells as you suggested, so that's what I've started to do since creating this thread. Thanks for answering though! :-)

Comment: glad to know my suggestion is acceptable. Let me know if you run into any roadblock :)

Comment: Well since you offered :P Now I'm trying to collate all the pieces into a collection that is easily workable with `TableLayoutPanel.Controls` and also has a `Find()` method similar (or preferably exactly the same) as `List<T>.Find()`. I can't seem to find that method in any of the `ICollection, IList, IEnumerable`, etc. interfaces so where the heck does it come from?! :S [Its offical MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) doesn't say much about it at all...

Comment: Yes I offered.....but not sure what you are asking. You have the information about no. of boxes in tablelayourpanel, what elase you need.....??

Comment: I need to be able to find a piece based upon certain criteria (black/white, position relative to another piece, etc.). I already have `internal abstract class Piece : PictureBox`, and those are added to the `TableLayoutPanel`'s cells. Now I need a `PieceCollection` class that inherits from `TableLayoutControlCollection` and whatever interface the `List<T>.Find()` comes from (if any). And if I can't simply use a current interface, how would I go about writing my own `Find()` method that uses a predicate in the same way as `List<T>.Find()`?

Comment: Explanation wont make things 100% clear. Still let me try and again let me suggest in my way. Create a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>`. Store the panel and its location in the dictionary created. Then update the dictionary when panel position is changed. Using `X` and `Y` location of panel, you can get to know the relative positions also...

Answer (score 2):

Your picture looks like the image is being scaled to the entire size of the form, rather than just to the area of the chess board.

Rather than using

```
this.Size
```

as a basis for scaling, try using

```
this.ClientSize
```

> The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form excluding the borders and the title bar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks but nope, that doesn't help :-( If I move the mouse really slowly while resizing, I can see that at certain sizes everything lines up great! But most of the time it doesn't...so could this have something to do with fractional pixels? While resizing a form, does the size move up (or down) in fractional increments, or whole increments only?

Comment: @Kenny83: Sizes are in whole, not fractional, pixels.  Glad you found a solution that works for you.